# Use alien to convert the RPM file into a .deb

Tags: rpm, 32-bit, deb

I am having a hard time installing the UC Berkeley version of Scheme. I have a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04, and per the installation instruction, I'd need a 32-bit system. Here is the installation guide: [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~scheme/precompiled/Linux/](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Escheme/precompiled/Linux/)

It is said that:

> For Debian GNU/Linux on a pure64 (amd64) system: Use a 32-bit computer
> to 'alien STk-4.0.1-ucb1.3.6.i386.rpm' On the 64-bit computer, run
> 'apt-get install ia32-libs' copy the $STK.deb file from the 32-bit
> computer to the local amd64 ......

Therefore, I'd appreciate if someone who has a 32-bit system can kindly convert the RPM file to a deb file. Alternatively, it will be equally nice if someone can teach me how to do that on my 64-bit system.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 18.04 (64bit) I had to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/bzliu94/cs61a_fa07):

```
# Download 32bit rpm
wget http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~scheme/precompiled/Linux/STk-4.0.1-ucb1.3.6.i386.rpm

# install alien to convert rpm to deb
sudo apt-get install alien

# install 32bit library dependencies
sudo apt-get install libsm6:i386
sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1

# convert rpm to deb package targeting 64bit architecture
fakeroot alien --target=amd64 STk-4.0.1-ucb1.3.6.i386.rpm

# install deb package
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture stk_4.0.1-1_amd64.deb
```